# Decompose Scala sequence into member values

Tags: scala

I'm looking for an elegant way of accessing two items in a `Seq` at the same time. I've checked earlier in my code that the `Seq` *will* have exactly two items. Now I would like to be able to give them names, so they have meaning.

```
records
  .sliding(2) // makes sure we get `Seq` with two items
  .map(recs => {
    // Something like this...
    val (former, latter) = recs       
  })
```

Is there an elegant and/or idiomatic way to achieve this in Scala?

Comment: If you akways have two elements, why not accessing them by their index?

Comment: You mean like `val (former, latter) = (recs(0), recs(1))`? I have a feeling that it is not the most elegant way...

Comment: _most elegant_ is highly subjective. If the structure of your list is guaranteed, both ways are equally valid (I always think of Knuth's _premature optimisation_ quote when people look for the _most idiomatic_ way for a code snippet that is perfectly readable either way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is any more elegant, but you can also unpick the sequence like this:

```
val former +: latter +: _ = recs
```

Comment: Didn't have this on my radar, I like it - saves the pattern `match {}`

Comment: I assume the `_` is there because the compiler doesn't know that `recs` will have just two elements? Also, what this `+:` approach called, apart from "assignment"?

Comment: @mthmulders Regarding the name of the approach, I'd call it **infix value definition** (i.e. a value definition with an infix _pattern_ as LHS). Took me some digging but I found something about it in the [Scala spec on declarations and definitions](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#value-declarations-and-definitions) (scroll down under _Example_)

Comment: @mthulders Regarding the `_`, you need this even if you know your list has just two elements, since the last part of the pattern matches the remainder of the list, which is some form of List (even if empty). I.e. if you remove `_`, `latter` would then become a _List with the second element_, whereas you want it to be the element itself. You can read your value definition like this: _A list with two elements (named former and latter) followed by anything (which I happen to know is the empty List)_. That's why you can also use `Nil` (= empty List) if you know that you only have two elements.

Comment: @mthmulders Just to add, `_` is more general as it would also work for Lists with > 2 elements. If you use `Nil` and the list has more than 2 elements, you would get a `MatchError`.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the elements by their index:

```
map { recs => {
    val (former, latter) = recs(0), recs(1)       
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of `sliding` is a `List`. Using a pattern match, you can give name to these elements like this:

```
map{ case List(former, latter) => 
  ...
}
```

Note that since it's a pattern match, you need to use `{}` instead of `()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern matching to decompose the structure of your list:

```
val records = List("first", "second")

records match {
    case first +: second +: Nil => println(s"1: $first, 2: $second")
    case _                      => // Won't happen (you can omit this)
}
```

will output

> 1: first, 2: second

Answer (score 0):

For a records of known types (for example, Int):

```
records.sliding (2).map (_ match { 
  case List (former:Int, latter:Int) => former + latter })
```

Note, that this will unify element (0, 1), then (1, 2), (2, 3) ... and so on. To combine pairwise, use sliding (2, 2):

```
val pairs = records.sliding (2, 2).map (_ match { 
  case List (former: Int, latter: Int) => former + latter
  case List (one: Int) => one 
}).toList
```

Note, that you now need an extra case for just one element, if the records size is odd.